# Is there any limit on number of apps a user can have on facebook?

Tags: facebook

Is there any limit on number of apps a single user can have on Facebook? If a developer is working with a company and they have hundreds of clients, is it possible to keep all apps in one user profile?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, tools, or [other off-site resource are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook hasn't set a limit on apps you can create. But having more apps in one dashboard would be hard to manage. Always a good idea to keep it manageable.